# Validators in POS

Tags: transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp, proof-of-stake, serenity, reward

note: Simple, layman, language would be highly appreciated!

Hello,

So, what would a 'validator'
(after switching from PoW to Pos on Ethereum) 
actually, do? Specifically?

Would he be required to manually check each and every transaction made on Ethereum, confirming its legitimacy and thereafter finalizing it?

Or, would he be required, 'only', to keep the blockchain up to date, and taking precautions for his part - as a validator - to work smoothly? (Not allowing any internet outages on his own computer, etc...?)

(... and if second is the case, could some awesome person perhaps point to the direction of doing so? :) ... 
...I'm not that highly educated in the computer sciences' and any pointer would be great! 
(For example, an advice that would point to a certain cloud provider? and what exact service? ... Maybe some extra precautions with the internet provider that is possible to get? )

Thanks for the answers, best regards and I'll see you in serenity! 
AA